# How to align <p> and <a> tags side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<p>` tag and an `<a>` tag that I'd like to have vertically aligned and side-by-side. To give you an idea of what I have so far, this is my code:

HTML:

```
<p class="c2a-content">This is just a test. Hopefully it will line up properly!</p>
<a href="#" class="button">My Button</a>
```

CSS:

```
.c2a-content{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}

.button{
    background:#008ed7;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:25px 35px;
    float:left;
}

.button:hover{
    /*background:#007DBD;*/
    background:#0087CC;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

The way things are now, the paragraph is the full width of my container and the button sits below that. How can I get the paragraph to fill up 2/3 of the container and have the button fill up the other 1/3?

Comment: give it a width of 73%

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5qhW5/ Seems fine here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The point:** The floated element should be placed before everything in the *container*.

When you put the *paragraph* at first, it takes up all the width of its parent. And the floated element will be rendered after the paragraph.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="button">My Button</a>
  <p class="c2a-content">This is just a test. Hopefully it will line up properly!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden; /* clear fix hack */
}

.c2a-content {
  text-align:left;
  background-color: gold; /* Just for demo */
  margin: 0;              /* Override user agent stylesheet to align vertically */
}

.button {
  /* Other CSS declarations */
  float: right;       /* float the button to the right */
  margin-left: 10px;  /* make a space between button and the paragraph */
}
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/iXiBIKi/2/edit)**.

**Note:** If you need to pull out the *paragraph* from behind of the floated *button*, you could set `overflow-x: hidden;` on the *paragraph* or simply set a `margin-left` property.

Here is the **[JSBin Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/iXiBIKi/3/edit)**.

Comment: That works just like I'd want it to except I'd prefer the button to be on the right...Is that possible?

Comment: @user2730418 give me a moment ;)

Comment: @user2730418 Done, check the demo again.