# CSS space display: table-cell out

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have code that dynamically generates `<ul>` lists each with two `<li>` in them. I want those to be displayed next to each other / broken into the next line if there isn't enough room anymore.

Currently I have this

```
ul.pictureBlocks{
   display: table-cell;
}
```

This displays them next to each other with 0 space between them. I tried `border-spacing` and `margin` or `padding` but nothing worked. When I used `display: table` on the ul tag it got the spacing from `border-spacing` but displayed them beneath each other.

Comment: display:table for parent and table-cell for childs

Comment: try `display:inline-block` and then padding or margin...

Comment: make a fiddle or a codepen with what you tried :)

Comment: `margin` is [not applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346083/space-between-divs-display-table-cell/18346159#18346159) to `table-cell` elements. Either [float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521125/how-to-align-p-and-a-tags-side-by-side/18521184#18521184) the list items, or use [`inline-block`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409424/display-list-item-elements-in-different-columns/21409646#21409646) to display them beside each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

```
.pictureblocks{
   display: inline-table;
   border-spacing: 10px;
   border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: inline-block + margin:10px would do too :) , lots of interesting things there for you  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

Comment: inline-block and margin doesn't actually work. I tried it. I tried all the solutions but inline-table is the only one working for me

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to give space between li and align them horizontally.

/--CSS Code---/

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
ul li{display:inline-block; background-color:#ef8913; padding:5px;}
ul li a{ color:blue}
```

/--HTML Code --/

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
```

Try this link. `http://jsbin.com/kunavupa/1/edit`

Answer (score 0):

try `display:inline-block` and then padding or margin...

```
ul li{
   display: inline-block;
    background:red;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5pPT/)